# excel, how to use a own reference (dynamic) for a range cells to append a conditional validation. Check HEX

Tags: excel, validation, excel-2010, hex

EXCEL

I try to figure out HOW to add for a range of cells a validation for HEX-decimal input.

DATA VALIDATION >> CUSTOM >>
For CELL E16, it works fine like this

```
=IF(AND(LEN(E16)<=2;ISNUMBER(HEX2DEC(E16)));TRUE;FALSE)
```

So to reference to the cell self can be done as following
(use CHAR(64 +  *-> 65 is A and*  COLUMN() *gives a number A -> 1 *

```
=(CONCATENATE(CHAR(64+COLUMN());ROW()))
```

So I thought

```
=IF(AND(LEN(INDIRECT((CONCATENATE(CHAR(64+COLUMN());ROW()))))<=2;ISNUMBER(HEX2DEC(INDIRECT((CONCATENATE(CHAR(64+COLUMN());ROW()))))));TRUE;FALSE)
```

Has somebody an idea to make it easy to do it for a big range ...

Thanks

Kris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the answer already:

- apply your posted data validation to cell **E16**
- copy cell **E16**
- select a block of other cells
- PasteSpecial > Validation

The formula will auto-adjust over the range of pasted cells.

Comment: with a lot of pleasure, just like I received your answer